# Set PHP session via cURL - will it set the session for the client or the server?

Tags: php, curl, session-variables

I have a website that uses PHP sessions to manage logged in users.  Another company has asked for their users to sign in to their site and then when they come to my site, the user will automatically be signed in.

To do this we are using cURL to post the user details from their site to my site, where I validate them and create a session to log them in.

What I can't get my head around though is:  will the session be created for the server that sent the cURL POST or for the user's computer?  If the other site posts data to my site and I create a session based on successful login, when the user comes to my site, will they be logged in?

I have only just started building the mechanism to do this and wanted to check before I get too far - I'm beginning to think that it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session will be created for the server which make the curl request, not the final client. What you can do is generate a token when the server make a curl request, then give this token to the final client who will request your site with this token. Then you can check this token to log him in

Comment: Ah OK - thanks, I've marked your answer as accepted as you were first to propose it.  I will store the token in my db, send it back to them and then tell them to include it in the URL when sending the user to my site.  I'll also make the token only valid for minutes after being initially set for security.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this method will not work. When you create a PHP session, it will be bound to the computer making the request - in this case, that would be the other server.

You need to determine a method by which to identify the user when they visit your website. This could be a token as mguimard suggested, a 3rd party cookie, or even just their IP address (though I would highly recommend against using Ip for this). Once you settle on an identification method, you just store that identifier in memory/databse somewhere. When A user comes to your site with an identifier, retrieve it from storage and autoamtically create their new session.

Answer (score 1):

First of all session will work only on your own browser / "user's computer".For example I logged in to a site, I used a session so this session will keep alive in my computer browser only. but when I close the browser the session will be destroyed. so to keep the session alive you will need cookies. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible for you to create a session for those who not logged in your site, you just create a session for the server, and of course it does not work

you can ask the server to build the mechanism, while a new user log in , redirect the user to your site to create the session, then you redirect back to the server automatically

or you can implement a same session id method with the server, eg, ip+useragent,
what you need to do is to sync the session from the server, or the server push sessions to you